# How to perform some action when my Android app is launched

Tags: android

I am creating an android App. I want a voice sort of message something which will execute when the app launches . I have already figured out the message part using TEXT TO SPEECH, but cannot execute it automatically on app startup.Can Anybody help me out ?

Comment: Have you tried using the onCreate method of your main activity?

Comment: put the main Activity code here and we better help you

Comment: Depends on what you mean on "app startup", if you are talking about your first launch, use the Application class. If you are talking about when entering the specific activity on its first launch use onPostCreate, if you are talking about every time when entering the activity use onStart or onResume.

Comment: Thanks buddy A Steenbergen ! Worked like a Charm.

Comment: Added my task into the onStart and Voila , Big Thanks Bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute code only once when the app starts, then this could be one possible solution:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public MyApp() {
        // this method fires only once per application start. 
        // getApplicationContext returns null here

        Log.i("main", "Constructor fired");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();    

        // this method fires once as well as constructor 
        // but also application has context here

        Log.i("main", "onCreate fired"); 
    }
}
```

Then you should register this class as your application class inside `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MyApp"> <------- here
    <activity android:name="MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```